# C++ Template Design vs Inheritance Hierarchy

Tags: c++, boost

In studying boost graph, I've noticed that they utilize concepts, metaprogamming, and traits etc.. My question, when considering design options, is there any reason they did not utilize a more traditional inheritance scheme, besides performance. For example, a parent "graphContainer" class that adjacency_list, adjacency_matrix, etc... inherit from combined with interfaces for bfs, dfs, and the algorithms that each can implement. To generalize, can someone discuss the relative benefits of their parallel (horizontal design) in c++ to the more vertical one of inheritance for generic programming?

To rephrase, is their any inherent characteristics of graph based problems, containers, etc... that lend itself to these design patterns, if we're performance agnostic.

Comment: This is discussed in the documentation, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/.  Look under "Algorithm/Data-Structure Interoperability".

Comment: That isn't the only way to solve the problem however, one could still write generic interface classes to achieve the linear bound. They don't discuss the alternatives in enough detail to be clear.

Comment: Are you wanting more detail on the trade-offs of generic programming vs. object-oriented programming?

Comment: That may describe my question, as long as you're not concluding that I'm considering the two mutually exclusive. I suppose I'm essentially just curious when OOP patterns are more efficient than these template based alternatives.

Comment: Although they aren't entirely mutually exclusive, it is the difference between static vs dynamic polymorphism. Static polymorphism has the advantage that you don't have to inherit from any particular base class to be able to use the algorithms, but yes there are downsides as well.  These trade-offs are not specific to a graph library though.

Comment: "I suppose I'm essentially just curious when OOP patterns are more efficient than these template based alternatives." - they never are. These are orthogonal. It's just that if the library design does not **force** runtime polymorphism, then the library user gets to choose. So it serves strictly more options.